# RDP latency optimisation on worldwide connections

Tags: rdp, remote, terminal-server, latency, geolocation

I'm wondering how bigger companys are working around this challenge.
Our company gets bigger and therefore we're starting to expand in new countries.

Now a new branch office opened straight at the other site of the globe. Of course these Users need to connect to our Windows Terminalserver. Unfortunately they've got a (ping) latency with 300 - 800 ms which (we think) is the source of the complaints (slow screen refresh / buildup on RDP sessions)

Are there any recommendation or best practises how this setup can be optimized?

I'm very thankful for every advise
Kind regards